# vert.x WebClient handshake fails with host using letsEncrypt certificate

Tags: java, ssl, vert.x

Trying to connect to a https server that uses LetsEncrypt certificate using vert.x 3.7.1 on JVM 1.8.0_152. While it works e.g. with `www.google.com` I get a `javax.net.ssl.SSLException`: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

My code:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.ext.web.client.WebClient;
import io.vertx.ext.web.client.WebClientOptions;

public class ClientTest extends AbstractVerticle {

    private WebClient webClient;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Runner.runVerticle(ClientTest.class.getName(), true);
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        ClientTest clientTest = new ClientTest();
        vertx.deployVerticle(clientTest);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        WebClientOptions clientOptions = new WebClientOptions()
                .setMaxInitialLineLength(10000).setLogActivity(true)
                .setTryUseCompression(true).setSsl(true).setTrustAll(true)
                .setVerifyHost(false);

        webClient = WebClient.create(vertx, clientOptions); 
        Set<String> hostList = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("www.wissel.net","www.google.com"));

        hostList.forEach(host -> {
            System.out.println("Connecting to "+host);
            webClient.get(443, host, "/")
            .send(ar -> {
                if (ar.failed()) {
                    ar.cause().printStackTrace();
                } else {
                    System.out.println(host+" returnCode:"+ ar.result().statusCode());
                }
            });
        });

    }   
}
```

I'm trying to run this on a Mac.
What do I miss?

Comment: Per ssllabs, that **server only supports 256-bit AES** (and TLS version 1.2). At least for Oracle Java, 8u151/2 is the first version that doesn't require downloading 'unlimited crypto policy' files for 256-bit, but it DOES still require you **edit `JREHOME/lib/security/java.security`** to set `crypto.policy=unlimited`. (The _next_ version, 8u161/2, has unlimited by default.) I don't know where JREHOME is on Mac; you'll have to do that part yourself.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - bingo. Can you turn your comment into an answer, so you can take proper credit for it?